# How to develop Android apps without Android Studio, but with Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to write Android apps without Android Studio?

I know languages like C and java. The problem is the following: I have a 4 GB RAM system and as you all know, android studio is hungry for memory. I have tried to reduce Android Studio's memory usage by disabling some plugins. One of the sources I have seen is This: *[Solving Android Studio High Memory Usage Problems](https://techzog.com/development/android-studio-high-ram-usage/)*

However, I still have problems, particularly with my screen reader crushing and needing to constantly restart screen reader to read out contents of the window. So, my thinking was, is there a way to develop apps with IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), for example, or even simpler, [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and then somehow build the project?

The issue with this is project file structure creation, which has a lot of files, etc. Besides that, Android Studio has powerful capabilities for debugging on device, managing dependencies, APIs, etc. Is there some way to do this (possibly harder way), but without Android Studio?

I prefer developing native vs hybrid or web applications. I have even tried Python and developing some apps with [BeeWare](https://pypi.org/project/beeware/), but I still prefer native.

Comment: Are you running and debugging your code on an emulator or physical device?

Comment: on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with Visual Studio code by using [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)). Also, your app will be able to run on Android and iOS.

Comment: will android studio be totally omitted and I'll get fine with using just the tools, or android studio will still be in connection? Thanks in advance.