# Android app development, with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code

I want to create and build mobile apps using Visual Studio Code.

I have the environment for Node.js, Java, and Python installed. I don’t have any idea on how to use these to create and build mobile apps.
I can't install Android Studio for some reasons, and I don't know how to get the Android SDK without installing Android Studio.
I can only use Visual Studio Code.

How could I still create and build android apps using Visual Studio Code?

---

Related: *[How to develop Android apps without Android Studio, but with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668775/how-to-develop-android-apps-without-android-studio-but-with-visual-studio-code)*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

It may be helpful to use the tips from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/w8cr8r/comment/iuimngg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Here one of the participants talks about his experience of developing in Visual Studio Code and how to set up his editor. Here are some excerpts from that comment:

> - Install Java JDK (presumably you will have one - if not, openjdk-8 will do)
> - Download command line [SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools)
> - Unzip into ~/android
> - Configure $ANDROID_HOME and add the tools to your $PATH
> - Finally, sdkmanager will do the rest, you will probably want to do sdkmanager --install "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.2" "emulator" for emulating and building for most of the hardware in the wild.

---

Also this comment mentions environment variables:

> Some useful environment variables you might want to set (put these in > your .bashrc or .bash_aliases - or if you're on Windows, edit the > system environment variables from the System dialog by right clicking My Computer):

> - export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android
> - export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin:$PATH
> - export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
> - export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

---

In addition, [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/w8cr8r/comment/iuinbai/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in the same thread mentions extensions for Visual Studio Code:

> - [Android Id](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adelphes.android-dev-ext): adelphes.android-dev-ext (Android debugging support for VS Code)
> - [Android iOS Emulator Id](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate): DiemasMichiels.emulate (Run Android emulator and iOS simulator easily from VScode)
> - [Android System Tools Id](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flimberger.android-system-tools): flimberger.android-system-tools (Syntax support for file formats used in Android system development)

Comment: I can only use Visual Studio Code, thanks though.

Comment: Updated about VSC

Comment: Thanks, I found a different question that has an answer. (View related link) I am going to try that out.

Comment: I would _really_ recommend against using Eclipse and ADT in 2023.  [Development/support ended in 2016](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html), for one thing.  For another, you have no real Gradle support integrated into ADT, which means you'll struggle to use virtually every library that exists today...  It's gonna be a bad time.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse In last edit information about Eclipse was removed

Answer (score 2):

You can create and still develop Android apps using Visual Studio Code without having to use Android Studio.

**1. I assume you have Visual Studio Code installed** (if you haven't, install it - https://code.visualstudio.com/ )

**2. Install the Java Development Kit (JDK)**, you can download it here (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/)

**3. Install Android SDK without downloading Android Studio**, link to [[https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads]](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads)

- 3.1 Go to the Android Command Line Tools page
- 3.2 Scroll down to "Command-line tools only" and download the SDK for your operating system.

  [This is what you should see in the section "Command-line tools only"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IyIM.jpg)
- 3.3 Extract the downloaded SDK to a preferred location on your computer.

**4. Configure environment variables for Android SDK** (for Windows only)

**5. Install Visual Studio Code Extensions**:
to. Kotlin language

- 5.1. Android XML
- 5.2. Android Snippets
- 5.3. Debugger for Java

And then proceed with the configurations you run on any project.

Comment: Which environment variables (that is the only thing I still need, if you provide that you will get the green tick)

Comment: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is a variable required for Android app development. It points to the path to the folder where the Android SDK (Software Development Kit) is installed, which contains all the tools and libraries needed to develop, compile, and test Android applications.

Comment: To set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, follow these steps:

1. Right-click "This PC" or "Computer" and select "Properties".

2. Click "Advanced system settings" on the left.

3. In the System Properties window, click the "Environment Variables" button.

4. Under "System Variables", click "New" to add a new environment variable.

5. Variable name: ANDROID_HOME

6. Variable value: Path to your Android SDK folder (for example, C:\path\to\folder\android-sdk).

7. Click "OK" to save the environment variable.

Comment: How do I then build the app?

Comment: Create an android project:

Open the terminal or command window and navigate to the directory where you want to build your project.

Use the Android command-line tool to create a new Android project. For example, run the following command to create a project with the name "MyApp" and the package "com.example.myapp":
[ npx create-react-native-app MyApp --package=com.example.myapp ]
This command will use the "Create React Native App" (CRNA) CLI, which is a tool that allows you to create a React Native project with support for Java (Android) and Node.js.

Comment: what is com.example and how do I get access to react native

Comment: [ --package=com.example.myapp ] =>This is an optional flag that allows you to specify the package name for your Android app. In this case, the package name is set to com.example.myapp. The package name uniquely identifies your Android app in the Google Play Store and other app markets.

Comment: Once you run this command, the React Native project will be created, and you can start developing your app using JavaScript/React for the front-end logic and add native modules (Java for Android, Objective-C/Swift for iOS) if needed.

Comment: npm is right now installing the packages, thank you!

Comment: Thanks to you for the green tick, if you ever have problems and would like some advice you can contact me via the contact form on https://devfrancescamazzeo.com/ . Happy coding!

Comment: An Error occured saying ANDROID_HOME variable is not set...

Comment: And there is a typo on your website: "I love craete new software" -> "I love creating new software"

Comment: I have corrected the error, thanks for the feedback

Comment: The typo or the ANDROID_HOME variable?

Comment: I fixed the typo... regarding the environment variable error (sorry I didn't get notification of that comment) follow the steps to create the ANDROID_HOME variable and this time try creating it in the "User variables for [nameuser]" section

Comment: "System can't find Path"

Comment: I tried everything I can, but nothing works

Comment: The typo is still there

Comment: The error message you encountered, "ANDROID_HOME system not found path," typically indicates that the environment variable ANDROID_HOME is not set or configured correctly.

Comment: 1. Check Android SDK Installation: Make sure you have installed the Android SDK on your computer. 2.Update PATH Environment Variable:

Make sure that the Android SDK's tools and platform-tools directories are added to your system's PATH variable.
For example, on Windows, you might need to add %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools to the PATH.
On macOS / Linux, you'd add $ANDROID_HOME/tools and $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools.

Comment: 3.Verify Configuration: Open a new terminal or command prompt and type echo %ANDROID_HOME% (Windows) or echo $ANDROID_HOME (macOS / Linux). If the correct path is displayed, then the environment variable is set up correctly.

Comment: 4. Restart or Refresh Environment: After making these changes, restart your computer or open a new terminal window to ensure the environment variables take effect.

Comment: Which Path variable? what do the "%" symbols stand for?

Comment: When I am coding it is often so troublesome

Comment: In Windows, environment variables are enclosed in % symbols to distinguish them from regular text. For example, %ANDROID_HOME% represents the value of the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

on ARM MAC OS it would appear that 'android' command is deprecated.

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

I really would have liked to avoid using another IDE (Android Studio) but it appears that isn't possible.